# How to evaluate Bessel functions $K_{i x+\frac{9}{4}}(2\pi)+K_{i x-\frac{9}{4}}(2\pi)$ with $x>1.5*10^8$ in Mathematica 7?

Tags: riemann-zeta, mathematica

I am trying to evaluate Bessel functions $K_{i x+\frac{9}{4}}(2\pi)+K_{i x-\frac{9}{4}}(2\pi)$ with $x>1.5*10^8$ in Mathematica 7.  This function is the first Polya approximation to Riemann $\xi(s)$ function.

In Mathematica language these two Bessel functions are represented as 
"BesselK[I x+9/4,2Pi]+BesselK[I x-9/4,2Pi]"

At $x=1.0*10^8$, I got "$-1.28351162994662*10^{-68218805}+0.*10^{-68218820} i$"

At $x=1.5*10^8$, I got error message:
"General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation."

Thanks-
Mike

Comment: Have you tried to get an asymptotic approximation?

Comment: @O.L. Yes. I just found an asymptotic approximation and am working on the numerical calculation. Thanks!

Comment: Actually these approximations are known - [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.45) refers to [this paper](http://dlmf.nist.gov/bib/D#bib688).

Comment: @O.L. Thanks again. I will take a look.